# Issue with "shift_jis" Convertor

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, encoding, shift-jis

I am using Japanese as the default locale and trying to run my application in localized mode. The application uses ICU 63.1.

```
$ ./icuinfo.exe
Plugins are disabled.
 <icuSystemParams type="icu4c">
    <param name="copyright"> Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others. License & terms of use: http://www.unicode.org/copyright.html </param>
    <param name="product">icu4c</param>
    <param name="product.full">International Components for Unicode for C/C++</param>
    <param name="version">**63.1**</param>
    <param name="version.unicode">11.0</param>
    <param name="platform.number">1000</param>
    <param name="platform.type">Windows</param>
    <param name="locale.default">en_IN</param>
    <param name="locale.default.bcp47">en-IN</param>
    <param name="converter.default">ibm-5348_P100-1997</param>
    <param name="icudata.name">icudt63l</param>
    <param name="icudata.path">.\</param>
    <param name="cldr.version">34.0</param>
    <param name="tz.version">2018e</param>
    <param name="tz.default">Asia/Calcutta</param>
    <param name="cpu.bits">32</param>
    <param name="cpu.big_endian">0</param>
    <param name="os.wchar_width">2</param>
    <param name="os.charset_family">0</param>
    <param name="uconfig.internal_digitlist">1</param>
    <param name="uconfig.have_parseallinput">1</param>
 </icuSystemParams>.
```

When the application starts the internal library tries to create a converter for "shift_jis" but everytime it gets consistently failed with the "*'shift_jis' Invalid convertor name*" error.

```
     UConverter *conv = ucnv_open("shift_jis", &status);
```

The application is running on Windows Server 2016 Standard.

I am not sure what is causing this and how to resolve this?

Ideally, it should not give any error. It was working before when the application was running on Windows Server 2012 with ICU version 38 but after the upgrade, it just got broke somehow.

Could this be an environment issue?

I tried to find similar issue on Unicode but didn't find any relevant information.

Comment: Interesting: you get the same error if you try directly in Unicode site: https://icu4c-demos.unicode.org/icu-bin/convexp?conv=Shift_JIS (and if Google know such address, I think there is a bug (or maybe on some release notes they discontinued it, possibly because if may not be unique)